Using signInWithPopup and offscreen documents on a chrome extension to sign a user in with firebase, how do I persist auth state to background.js
I followed these docs , and the problem is within signInWithPopUp I am authenticated, but within my background.js if I listen for auth.onStateChange, nothing is triggered. I can't get the current users signed in state either (I could use local storage but I need firebase auth to work), I think it's due to reinitialising the app, but since they are hosted separately what can I do. I need the user to be authenticated here so that I can add rtdb rules to only allow authenticated users to do certain things, and without it persisting from offscreen document to background.js it wont work. I get permission denied on authentication, when I make a request from background.js.
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);
const auth = getAuth();

const OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT_PATH = "/offscreen.html";

// Helper function to check if an offscreen document is already active
async function hasDocument() {
  const matchedClients = await clients.matchAll();
  return matchedClients.some(
    (c) => c.url === chrome.runtime.getURL(OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT_PATH)
  );
}

// Set up an offscreen document if it doesn't exist
async function setupOffscreenDocument(path) {
  if (!(await hasDocument())) {
    if (creating) {
      await creating;
    } else {
      creating = chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
        url: path,
        reasons: [chrome.offscreen.Reason.DOM_SCRAPING],
        justification: "authentication",
      });
      await creating;
      creating = null;
    }
  }
}

// Close the offscreen document if it exists
async function closeOffscreenDocument() {
  if (await hasDocument()) {
    await chrome.offscreen.closeDocument();
  }
}

// Function to get Firebase authentication
async function getAuthPopup() {
  try {
    const auth = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      type: "firebase-auth",
      target: "offscreen",
    });
    if (auth?.name === "FirebaseError") {
      throw new Error(auth.message || "Firebase authentication error");
    }
    return auth;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

// Firebase authentication process
async function firebaseAuth() {
  try {
    await setupOffscreenDocument(OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT_PATH);

    const auth = await getAuthPopup();

    // Persist user data in chrome.storage.local
    await chrome.storage.local.set({
      user: auth.user,
      accessToken: auth._tokenResponse.oauthAccessToken,
    });

    await saveUserToDatabase(auth.user);
    // Notify success
    return auth;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Authentication error:", error.message);
    throw error;
  } finally {
    await closeOffscreenDocument();
  }
}

// Check if a user exists in the database
async function userExists(userId) {
  const dbRef = ref(database);
  const snapshot = await get(child(dbRef, `Users/${userId}`));
  return snapshot.exists();
}

// Save user to Firebase Realtime Database
async function saveUserToDatabase(user) {
  const userId = user.uid;
  if (!(await userExists(userId))) {
    await set(ref(database, `Users/${userId}`), {
      name: user.displayName || null,
      created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
    });
  } else {
    console.log(`User ${userId} already exists in database.`);
  }
}

This would always error at userExists. Simplified rules for testing:
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}

Tried setting persistence on the signInWithPopup, and I expected to have the same user signed in, in my background.js

Remove closeOffscreenDocument and handle the auth and its events inside the offscreen document.

@woxxom you're right. I appreciate it.

@woxxom how would this work with requests which have live updates, like onValue. I managed to configure the rest, but since onValue I have to do in my index.js I have had to leave the db rule on read: true. Everything else is fine, I have locked down the writing requests.
